# How to handle null pointer exception while reading excel date column value using getDateCellValue() method of Apche poi

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-poi

I am reading excel file throughly and I have a condition like if `columnType` is "date" then set `getCellDateValue` otherwise using `formatter` and `formatCellValue`:

```
String valueOfColumn = StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(excelData.getColumnType(), "date")
                            ? format(cell.getDateCellValue(), "dd/MM/yyyy")
                            : formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
excelData.setColumnValue(valueOfColumn );
```

It's working fine for all the column whether it's having value or not but if the date column is null, it's throwing `NullPointerException`.

Why is it throwing this exception and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: If `cell` is `null` then `cell.getDateCellValue()` must throw `NullPointerException`. So you need checking whether `cell` is `null` and only if not you can call `cell.getDateCellValue()`.

Comment: Thanks but if I put one null check before assigning the value to valueOfColumn then it will ignore all the null column values like

        if(cell != null){
        String valueOfColumn = StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(excelData.getColumnType(), "date")
                            ? format(cell.getDateCellValue(), "dd/MM/yyyy")
                            : formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
excelData.setColumnValue(valueOfColumn 
);
}

but I only want the null check for date column. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Get rid of the inflexible ternary operator and check `if (cell != null)` only before calling `cell.getDateCellValue()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is there in the [Apache poi documentation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.1/) itself that the method `getDateCellValue()` you are calling returns `null` for blank cells.So, most probably the `format()` method must be throwing null pointer exception because of this. Whenever your code encounters an empty cell value when the column type is 'date', it returns null which the `format()` method tries to format and throws exception.

> java.util.Date getDateCellValue()
>
> Get the value of the cell as a date.
>
> For strings we throw an exception. For blank cells we return a null.
>
> Returns:
>       the value of the cell as a date

So in short , you need to add a null check in your code to handle this case.

```
    String valueOfColumn;
   if(cell != null ) {
    if(StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(excelData.getColumnType(), "date") && cell.getDateCellValue() != null) {
      valueOfColumn = format(cell.getDateCellValue(), "dd/MM/yyyy");
    } else {
      valueOfColumn = formatter.formatCellValue(cell)
    }
     excelData.setColumnValue(valueOfColumn );
   }
   else {
   // handle else case for cell being null
   }
```

Comment: cell.getDateCellValue() != null    it's throwing null pointer exception

Comment: @Tech_sharma Then your `cell` is null. Add null pointer check for `cell` as well.